What is a good replacement for OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext?
I'm writing an addin for microsoft office word and I want to upload the current document to microsoft sharepoint.
Problem is the authentication:
In the past you could use OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext which shows a login prompt whenever user credentials are required. Since this one is deprecated I'm searching for an alternative that has the same login prompt behaviour (only the sharepoint url needed and no explizit name, password or ids required)
Cool thing with GetWebLoginClientContext was the fact that it wouldn't show up at all if users were already logged in.
Already looked into Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM) and PnP.Framework (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PnP.Framework/) but every function seems to require passwords, ids or secrets.
Since I'm already using CrmServiceClient in the same program, which has a "LoginPrompt=Auto" option, I don't want to annoy the user with more pop-up windows or anything.
Did I miss something?

@Stef...were you able to find the replacement?  I am having the same challenge.  Thanks!

@Stef - Were you able to find any other method to implement this. Thanks.
